# Declaring and modifying strings in C

Tags: c, string, variables

I've recently started to try learn the C programming language. In my first program (simple hello world thing) I came across the different ways to declare a string after I realised I couldn't just do `variable_name = "string data"`:

```
char *variable_name = "data"
char variable_name[] = "data"
char variable_name[5] = "data"
```

What I don't understand is the difference between them. I know they are different and one of them specifically allocates an amount of memory to store the data in but that's about it, and I feel like I need to understand this inside out before moving onto more complex concepts in C.

Also, why does using `*variable_name` let me reassign the variable name to a new string but `variable_name[number]` or `variable_name[]` does not? Surely if I assign, say, 10 bytes to it (`char variable_name[10] = "data"`) and try reassigning it to something that is 10 bytes or smaller it should work, so why doesn't it?

What are the empty brackets and the asterix doing?

Comment: I would suggest you to read [c-faq- 6. Arrays and Pointers](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

Comment: After reading the link suggested by @haccks, you might want to checkout [the section on strings](http://www.c-faq.com/charstring/index.html).

Comment: And don't make the mistake of thinking that `char name[10]` creates a little box of 10 chars that you can't copy larger strings into. You can, and you will suffer the horrible consequences only much later.

Comment: Thanks for the links

and @lister, would you mind being clear in what you're saying? that statement doesn't really tell me anything technical

Comment: @Linux_Noob It's no different than trying to make more than 10 items fit inside a box that clearly can only hold the 10 items you put into it. That box may break, or the contents can spill out from the top of the box that isn't closed. In the same way, your program can crash when you try to copy more than 10 chars, or it can misbehave (crash, functions as expected when it shouldn't, etc.) after the copy operation somehow succeeds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this declaration

```
char *variable_name = "data";
```

there is declared a pointer. This pointer points to the first character of the string literal "data". The compiler places the string literal in some region of memory and assigns the pointer by the address of the first character of the literal.

You may reassign the pointer. For example

```
char *variable_name = "data";
char c = 'A';

variable_name = &c;
```

However you may not change the string literal itself. An attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behaviour of the program.

In these declarations

```
char variable_name[] = "data";
char variable_name[5] = "data";
```

there are declared two arrays elements of which are initialized by characters of used for the initialization string literals. For example this declaration

```
char variable_name[] = "data";
```

is equivalent to the following

```
char variable_name[] = { 'd', 'a', 't', 'a', '\0' };
```

The array will have 5 elements. So this declaration is fully euivalent to the declaration

```
char variable_name[5] = "data";
```

There is a difference if you would specify some other size of the array. For example

```
char variable_name[7] = "data";
```

In this case the array would be initialized the following way

```
char variable_name[7] = { 'd', 'a', 't', 'a', '\0', '\0', '\0' };
```

That is all elements of the array that do not have explicit initializers are zero-initialized.

Pay attention to that in C you may declare a character array using a string literal the following way

```
char variable_name[4] = "data";
```

that is the terminating zero of the string literal is not placed in the array.
In C++ such a declaration is invalid.

Of course you may change elements of the array (if it is not defined as a constant array) if you want.

Take into account that you may enclose a string literal used as an initializer in braces. For example

```
char variable_name[5] = { "data" };
```

In C99 you may also use so-called destination initializers. For example

```
char variable_name[] = { [4] = 'A', [5] = '\0' };
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char variable_name[] = { [4] = 'A', [5] = '\0' };

    printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( variable_name ) );
    printf( "%zu\n", strlen( variable_name ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
6
0
```

When ypu apply standard C function `strlen` declared in header `<string.h>` you get that it returns 0 because the first elements of the array that precede the element with index 4 are zero initialized.

Comment: Thank you very much. This post cleared it up for me. Do I need to mark the thread as solved or anything? Also how to I upvote your post if there is such a function on here?

Comment: @Linux_Noob  First of all see my updated post. You can mark it as the best answer.:)

Comment: @Linux_Noob; You have enough reputation to upvote. Just click on the arraow facing up on the top left of the answer. You can accept the answer by clicking on `V` mark on the top left of answer.

Comment: @Vlad I don't quite understand what's going on with those destination initialisers. Would you mind explaing what, for expample,[4] = 'A' is doing? And why would strlen not look at the entire array before returning a number? Since (as I assume after reading the replies to this thread and others) all strings in C are actually arrays of single chracters, shouldnt strlen return the length of the whole array?

Comment: @Linux_Noob When you use such a declaration char s[] = { [4] = 'A' }; then all elements that precede the element with index 4 are zero-initialized because they do not have explicit initializers. Function strlen counts symbols in a character array until it encounteres the terminating zero. As the first character of array s is zero initialized function strlen will return 0.