# Declare a String type in C

Tags: c, string, variables

I am quite new to C and I come from a Java background.

So, I wanted to declare a String and immediately tried this:

```
String text;
```

Then it tells me that the term "String" is not defined.
I searched trough the internet and found this:

```
char text[16] = { 'E','i','n',' ','l','a','n','g','e','r',' ','T','e','x','t','\0' };
```

But this isn't very nice and too much work. There must be an other, better method.
Maybe with importing something. Does anyone has a good solution to this?

Comment: You can simply `char text[] = "whatever..."`.

Comment: This question may be useful: [Declaring and modifying strings in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30654242/declaring-and-modifying-strings-in-c)

Comment: I recommend you check out [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), and read some beginners books and tutorials.

Comment: C is way lower level than Java, and more deviously unforgiving, you are not going to go far by trying random stuff and hoping it works (especially since many many errors in C are "undefined behavior", which means that your program may appear to work, randomly crashing once in a while). Learn the language with a proper book.

Comment: It doesn't work because C is not Java... Also "isn't very nice and too much work" sums up C strings pretty well, there's a reason why all languages invented since C have their own string class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `C`, there is no standard data type called `String`. It is either a string literal or a `char` array.

FWIW,

```
char text[16] = { 'E','i','n',' ','l','a','n','g','e','r',' ','T','e','x','t','\0' };
```

can be shortened as

```
char text[ ] = { "Ein langer Text"};   //modifiable, but size limited to
                                       // the initalizer
```

or

```
char text[128] = { "Ein langer Text"};  // modifiable, with larger size than initializer
```

or

```
char *text = "Ein langer Text";  //not modifiable
```

Comment: actually `const char *const text = "Ein langer Text";` would be non modidiable (and prevents compiler to complain)

Comment: @OznOg I'm not saying you're wrong, but by definition, string literals are immutable. Attempt to change them will result in UB, anyways.

Comment: You can also leave out the parantheses, `char text[] = "Ein langer Text";` works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

There is no string type in C.

A string variable is a 1-d array of ASCII characters terminated by a null character.

The method you tried to declare a string is right.

```
char text[16] = { 'E','i','n',' ','l','a','n','g','e','r',' ','T','e','x','t','\0' };
```

But the easy one is to simply

```
char str[]="Ein Langer Text"
```

This is initialization is same as previous one but in this case compiler automatically inserts the null character at the end.

A simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
char str[]="Ein Langer Text";
int i;
for (i = 0; str[i]!='\0' ; ++i)
{
   printf("%c",str[i]);

}
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

You can even have a limited size string such as:

```
char[40]="whatever you want to keep here up to fourty characters";
```

Comment: Have an upvote just for leading with 'no string type in C'.

Comment: Is explanation not up to the point,misleading or wrong??

Comment: No - I just did not need to read any more before upvoting:)

Comment: I thought the other way anyways **thank you** :)

Answer (score 0):

It's even simpler:

```
char text[]="test 123";
```

or

```
char text[9]="test 123";
```

Answer (score -2):

in c, there is no string type:

in c you can try :

```
char *mystring = "Hello world";
```

i c++ you can try:

```
#include <iostream>

std::string mystring = "Hello";
```

Comment: Bad advice regarding that pointer to a string literal. String literals are read-only, so you need a pointer to a constant string, i.e. `const char *`.

Comment: It's a bad idea to give a C++ example to a C question. The languages are separate and distinct.